# Having the type error: Function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given), what could have stimulated this error call?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
    coor[0] = int(coor[0] * image_h)
    coor[2] = int(coor[2] * image_h)
    coor[1] = int(coor[1] * image_w)
    coor[3] = int(coor[3] * image_w)

    bbox_color = colors[class_ind]
    bbox_thick = int(0.6 * (image_h + image_w) / 600)
    c1, c2 = (coor[1], coor[0]), (coor[3], coor[2])
    cv2.rectangle(image, c1, c2, bbox_color, bbox_thick)
```

As the coordinates are already integer type as per the solutions provided here previously but the error in cv2.rectangle() is still occuring here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Umar, can you post your whole code?

Comment: The `cv2.rectangle` function needs the following properties of the rectangle to draw: horizontal top left coordinate, vertical top left coordinate, rectangle width and rectangle height. Looks like you are missing the last pair.

Comment: @eldesgraciado, cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness) in this syntax we can see that the height and width are defined by the start_point which is the top left corner, and end_point which is the bottom right corner of the bounding box, so is there anything missing still?